# AWS EC2 instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have two questions regarding EC2 and EBS.

1. Why do you need to create an EBS volume when creating an AMI ?
2. Why when I create an instance that is c3.2xlarge and comes with 2x80 SSD from my AMI why don't those two 80G SSDs appear in my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do you need to create an EBS volume when creating an AMI ?

Not necessary. You can create EBS backed AMI as well as Instance stored Backed AMIs. Read below links:

- [Creating an Amazon EBS-Backed Linux AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html)
- [Creating an Instance Store-Backed Linux AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html)

If your requirement is something specific, then please elaborate.

> Why when I create an instance that is c3.2xlarge and comes with 2x80 SSD from my AMI why don't those two 80G SSDs appear in my machine?

I just answered a similar question. Please find the [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22678430/1251660) on why you do not see the drives .

Comment: Cool thanks, that's a well explanation. So when I add those drives during the provisioning of the box, they would not be EBS volumes? Also does 2x80SSD mean I can add up to 2 80G SSDs?

Comment: Correct. Those are not EBS volumes. and Yes, you can add 2 drives of 80G SSD type in this case. For what drives are support for a specific instance type, please refer: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#instance-details